# ERROR: package.js is undifined

Tags: node.js, meteor, npm

I recently done some updates and added some packages based on recommendations from meteor

you know the usual `If you notice problems related to these missing modules, consider running: meteor npm install ...`

Problem now is that I get errors relating to the following

[image]

when I click to see which line is causing the issue, it's from var `EJSON = Package.ejson.EJSON;`

I don't know what this is therefore I am assuming I never messed with it during development.

any insight would be appreciated ...

EDIT: I went back through my commands, this issue started when I added `meteor add ecmascript` (solved one problem to open up another :))

Also as requested .meteor/packages

```
# Meteor packages used by this project, one per line.
# Check this file (and the other files in this directory) into your repository.
#
# 'meteor add' and 'meteor remove' will edit this file for you,
# but you can also edit it by hand.

autopublish@1.0.7
less@2.7.11
twbs:bootstrap@3.3.6
fortawesome:fontawesome
jquery@1.11.10
okgrow:router-autoscroll
meteor-base@1.3.0
mobile-experience@1.0.5
mongo@1.4.2
blaze-html-templates@1.0.4
session@1.1.7
tracker@1.1.3
logging@1.1.19
reload@1.2.0
random@1.1.0
ejson@1.1.0
spacebars@1.0.12
check@1.3.0
standard-minifier-css@1.4.0
standard-minifier-js@2.3.1
shell-server@0.3.1
kadira:flow-router
kadira:blaze-layout
zimme:active-route
accounts-ui@1.3.0
accounts-password@1.5.0
dynamic-import@0.3.0
http@1.4.0
percolate:synced-cron
matb33:collection-hooks
reactive-var
ecmascript
```

Comment: Can you revert to before package changes and try again? This isn't supposed to happen

Comment: I'm trying my best to. it's just that reverting means losing precious code.

Comment: Crazy idea, run `meteor reset`, delete every line from `.meteor/packages`, blow up node_modules with `rm rf node_modules`, and then paste packages back in and `meteor npm i`?

Comment: Can you edit to include your `.meteor/packages`?

Comment: That first error (about export statements) makes it look like ecmascript isn't parsing any files. AKA not working at all

Comment: What if you try to remove the `node_modules` folder and the `package-lock.json` and reinstall using `meteor npm install` ?

Comment: I've tried deleting the `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` then `meteor npm install` with no avail
I also edited to include my `.meteor/packages` file content

Comment: I'm guessing you are not running the latest version of meteor, but are stuck in an older version. Try putting `ecmascript` on top of the list of packages instead, but probably won't help. They've broken support for older versions by not restricting packages properly, so you either have to find someone else that has the old packages and copy them over in your .meteor directory or you will just have to upgrade to the latest meteor version + packages.

Comment: I am not sure how or why, I decided to start a new project, moved my core code there then added the packages one by one. Indeed ecmascript was the issue. Luckily it turns out that I can get by without it and I will just stick to that.